# Printing from IE pages blacks out text

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, printer

When users are printing pages from a specific site (containing important data) the print preview looks fine but the resulting print has all of the text lines blocked out with a square of black ink, Formatting and so on looks fine.

Are there any settings in IE/other browsers which may cause material with a certain flag to not be printed out properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any settings in IE/other browsers which may cause material with a certain flag to not be printed out properly?

Nope.

The site may have specific printer-based CSS styling in place in the page so that when you print it, it (intentionally) blacks out the content.

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp for more info on that.